# Identifying topic coverage from text

Tags: nlp, topic-model

I have been trying to understand a feasible approach to identify if given text talks about one of the given topics(also provided as text descriptions).
for e.g.

```
Text: "It was a great event Laura hosted, I wish to go again."
Topic 1 = "Last month revenues are in."
Topic 2 = "There was an event hosted."
Topic 3 = "A new event is being scheduled for the group."
```

In this example, Topic 2 is the most probable topic that the text talks about. It is possible that none of the topics match the text.

What I have tried till now is treating the problem as semantic similarity problem. I tried different models to create embeddings and computed cosine similarity score to identify if the text talks about the topic.

But the results haven't been good, mostly because semantically the text and topic are not necessarily similar.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem other than treating it as sentence similarity problem?